# SQL Server: stored procedure and send dbmail

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The reason of creating a stored procedure is to schedule a job to send a biweekly report to our staff (coordinators) using SQL Server db mail.

I'm having problems with getting it to work the right way. I don't usually work with cursors but couldn't find other choices.
Here's the issue. I tested the query by set criteria to send only to one Coordinator with one record "if @Coord_Email = 'lamez.sw1@gmail.com', where n.id = '43422546'". However the query been running over 5 minutes so i had to cancel it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_MZ_Coord_rpt_s9]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Member_ID VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE Report_S9 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT id
        FROM name
        WHERE status = 'a'

    OPEN Report_S9

    FETCH NEXT FROM Report_S9 INTO @member_ID 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Coord_ID Varchar(20)
        DECLARE @CO_ID    Varchar(20)
        DECLARE @Coord_Name Varchar(50)
        DECLARE @Coord_Email Varchar(50)

        SELECT @CO_ID = ID 
        FROM Relationship 
        WHERE id = @Member_ID 

        SELECT @Coord_ID = target_id 
        FROM Relationship 
        WHERE RELATION_TYPE = 'CO'

        SELECT @Coord_Name = FULL_NAME 
        FROM Name 
        WHERE ID = @Coord_ID  

        SELECT @Coord_Email = email 
        FROM Name 
        WHERE id = @Coord_ID

        IF @Coord_Email <> '' 
        BEGIN
            SELECT 
                n.id, n.CO_ID, n.FULL_NAME, a.TRANSACTION_DATE, a.UF_1, r.TARGET_ID
            FROM name n 
            INNER JOIN activity a ON n.id = a.id
            INNER JOIN Tops_Profile tp ON a.id = tp.ID
            INNER JOIN Relationship r ON n.CO_ID = r.ID
            WHERE 
                n.id = @member 
                AND UF_1 <> '' 
                AND (DATEDIFF(dd, TRANSACTION_DATE, GETDATE()) < 2)  
                AND r.RELATION_TYPE = 'co'
            ORDER BY 
                TRANSACTION_DATE

            EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
                    @profile_name =  'TOPS.ADMIN',
                    @recipients = @Coord_Email,
                    --@blind_copy_recipients = ,
                    @subject = 'S9 Report' 
 End

            FETCH NEXT FROM Report_S9 INTO @member_ID 
     END

     CLOSE Report_S9 
     DEALLOCAT Report_S9

     End
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you wrapping this in a transaction? You have no code to rollback the transaction and even if you did there is nothing to rollback. You also should consider changing your sp_ prefix habit (or even better no prefix at all). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: was a different script before. I've fixed that. is there any thing else you suggest?

Comment: Here is the issue. You stated "I'm having problems with getting it to work the right way.". What does that mean? What is it doing or not doing "the right way". We can help you with what is wrong but you have to explain to us what is wrong.

Comment: I tested the script by setting a criteria to send only to me  " if @Coord_Email = 'lamez.sw1@gmail.com' "  and retreive only one record "where n.id = '4342546'". the query been running for over 5 mins so i had to cancel it. What I'm seeking is if there's mistakes in this query that could be addressed.

Comment: There might be errors in there but we have no way to tell. We can't see your screen and we have no idea what your tables are like. We are not human sql compilers...in fact a sql compiler would have access to the data and the table structures which we don't have. There are so many reasons this could be running slow it is hard to know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The `FETCH NEXT` should be outside of your check for null. You need to continue the loop, even when there is nothing to do.

Comment: Good catch. If the OP has a row where email  = '' then they just created an endless loop.